# PHP String that is equal to $_POST will not change later, or maybe it is something else

Tags: php, string

I've been learning PHP in my spare time, and this is one of my "Hello, World" type scripts I'm doing for practice.

This is the code below, and the default strings will not change so the code will end up looping into eternity for I have no idea why:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["pbankroll"], $_POST["pstartbet"]))
{
    $bankroll = $_POST["pbankroll"];
    $startBet = $_POST["pstartBet"];

    //If using this code below instead of that above, everything will work fine:
    //$bankroll = 200;
    //$startBet = 25;

    while($bankroll >= $startBet)
    {
        $evenOrOdd=mt_rand(0,1);
        if ($evenOrOdd == 1)
        {
            $bankroll += $startBet;
            echo "Win ...... Bankroll is now: " . $bankroll . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $bankroll -= $startBet;
            echo "Loss ..... Bankroll is now: " . $bankroll . "<br>";
        }
    }

    echo "Probability, the Devourer of all Things!";
}
else
{ 
    echo "Please enter a bankroll and starting bet above.";
}
?>
```

The form to it:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Bankroll: <input type="text" name="pbankroll">
    Start Bet: <input type="text" name="pstartbet">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thank you, I should get in the habit of that.

Comment: There is no guarantee of any outcome to the above code. While there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the logic or the way the code is structured, if the "random" number gives 1 more or equal that it gives zero it will never stop. It won't stop until the random numbers are in deficit of 8.

Comment: @DaveRandom I hadn't realized that.
I'll see about putting a house edge on it. What's happening though, is that the values of the strings are never changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML name **pstartbet** needs to be changed to **pstartBet**.

Edit to clarify:

The **Start Bet** input element in the HTML form has the name **pstartbet** with the 'B' in lowercase. When PHP checks for that value, it's looking for **pstartBet** with the B capitalized. One of these two names needs to be changed so the cases match.

As it is:

```
$startBet = $_POST["pstartBet"]; // doesn't exist
```

This means that `$startBet` will be `null`. When cast to a number by the mathematical operations this will result in `0` - so the value of `$bankroll` will *never* change, and the loop will continue forever.

Comment: Well spotted. This is the answer. Although the proposed solution is incomplete, and this answer could do with an explanation of why this causes the problem. Also the OP needs to turn error reporting on in dev, as there is a warning being generated that would show what the problem is.

Comment: So this was it! Blast. Thanks for spotting it! I should have noticed this. I'll turn error reporting on in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to convert the incoming values to integer before using them in numerical operations:

```
$bankroll = intval($_POST["pbankroll"]);
$startBet = intval($_POST["pstartBet"]);
```

Or if they are float values use:

```
$bankroll = floatval($_POST["pbankroll"]);
$startBet = floatval($_POST["pstartBet"]);
```

Beside from this, the code can of course run forever. This is because of the pseudo randum numbers that are being used. If over a long time there are more 1's then 0's generated by `mat_rand()` then the code will run *forever*

Comment: That's a good point about using `intval`, but wouldn't the original value be casted as an integer when the addition or subtraction is done?

Comment: @woz. Although havin some experience with PHP, I would never answer this without testing it ;) give me a sec....

Comment: @woz yes it would, and the greater than/equal to would work as expected as well. This is not the answer, although it is a good idea.

Comment: I tried changing them to those, and it ends up looping still.

Comment: @Dimitto what values are you supplying? Is it possible that the values are evaluating to zero? You should show `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @hek2mgl true, but that shouldn't be an issue after the first iteration, because one of the operands will be an integer, so the other will be cast to an integer for the comparison. `20 > '100' === false`

Comment: @Dimitto Check the comments. It is correct, that the type cast isn't required - although I would recommend it. So the solution you are searching for may be more the second, random number related, part of the answer. Thanks to all ;)

Comment: @DaveRandom This is what I get: 
`array(2) { ["pbankroll"]=> string(3) "300" ["pstartbet"]=> string(3) "200" }`

Answer (score 1):

Consider that truly random numbers cannot be generated by a computer. Apparently `mt_rand` generates a pseudo-random number in such a way that it's causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the variables outside of the `if` clause & setting a default of `''` which basically means 'empty' & then having the if check if those two variables are empty or not.

```
<?php

$bankroll = array_key_exists("pbankroll", $_POST) ? intval($_POST["pbankroll"]) : '';
$startBet = array_key_exists("pstartbet", $_POST) ? intval($_POST["pstartbet"]) : '';

if (!empty($bankroll) && !empty($startBet))
{

    //If using this code below instead of that above, everything will work fine:
    //$bankroll = 200;
    //$startBet = 25;

    while($bankroll >= $startBet)
    {
        $evenOrOdd=mt_rand(0,1);
        if ($evenOrOdd == 1)
        {
            $bankroll += $startBet;
            echo "Win ...... Bankroll is now: " . $bankroll . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $bankroll -= $startBet;
            echo "Loss ..... Bankroll is now: " . $bankroll . "<br>";
        }
    }

    echo "Probability, the Devourer of all Things!";
}
else
{ 
    echo "Please enter a bankroll and starting bet above.";
}
?>
```